# Issue with app being repainted/re-rendered on every state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a gallery photo app with two sections. A **"Gallery"** section and a **"Selections"** section. Each photo in the **gallery** section has an **Add To Cart** button. When pressed that particular photo gets added to the **selections** section with several options to choose from, each option has an input box for a **Quantity** (visual representation below).

My problem is when I type the quantity (with each type), the app repaints, moves to the top of the page and loses focus on that particular input.

See this gif to see what I'm talking about

[image: photo-gallery.gif]

Below is the component (Excluding imports and unrelevant code).

When **Add to Cart** is pressed `handleAddSelection` is called and results in adding a photo object to `selectedPhotos` array state with the following format, then I display this under the **Selections** section.

```
{
  "path": "/client-photos/8/Esau Silva-3678-ytht6745.jpg",
  "label": "ytht6745.jpg",
  "packages": [
    {
      "optionID": 9,
      "description": "1-11x14",
      "price": 25,
      "type": "Individual Sheets",
      "quantity": 0
    },
    {
      "optionID": 8,
      "description": "1-16x10",
      "price": 35,
      "type": "Individual Sheets",
      "quantity": 0
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

When I type a number in one of the input boxes for each package option, I call `handleUpdateSelection`.

```js
import produce from 'immer';

const ClientPhotos = () => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [selectedPhotos, setSelectedPhotos] = useState([]);
  const { slug } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
        // Load photos
    const fetchClient = async () => {
        ...
        setClient(photos);
        ...
    }
  }, [slug]);

  const handleAddSelection = photo => {
    const packages = client.packageOptions.map(p => ({
      ...p,
      quantity: 0,
    }));
    const photoObject = {
      ...photo,
      packages,
    };

    setSelectedPhotos([...selectedPhotos, photoObject]);
  };

  const handleRemoveSelection = (e, photoLabel) => { ... };

  const handleUpdateSelection = (e, option, selectionIndex, packageIndex) => {
    const quantity = e.target.value;
    const { optionID } = option;

    // Get the specific photo from the state array
    const selection = selectedPhotos[selectionIndex];

    // Now update the quantity for the specific package in the selected photo
    const nextState = produce(selection, draft => {
      draft.packages[packageIndex].quantity = quantity;
    });

    // Finally update the app state array
    setSelectedPhotos(
      produce(selectedPhotos, draft => {
        draft[selectionIndex] = nextState;
      }),
    );
  };

  const Render = () => {
    return (
      <div className="container container-extended">
        <h1>{client.name} Photos</h1>
        <PhotoGallery
          photos={client.photos}
          handleAddSelection={handleAddSelection}
        />
        <PackageOptions />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const PackageOptions = () => {
    return (
      <section className="packages-content">
        <h2>Selections</h2>
        {selectedPhotos.map(({ label, packages }, selectionIndex) => (
          <Fragment key={label}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <p className="photo-label d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <strong>{label}</strong>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    title="Delete Selection"
                    onClick={e => handleRemoveSelection(e, label)}
                  >
                    <i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  </button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <Table borderless hover responsive>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Package Options</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                      <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {packages.map((p, packageIndex) => (
                      <tr key={p.optionID}>
                        <td>{p.description}</td>
                        <td>{currencyFormatter.format(p.price)}</td>
                        <td>
                          <Input
                            className="quantity"
                            onKeyPress={numbersOnly}
                            onChange={e =>
                              handleUpdateSelection(e,p,selectionIndex,packageIndex,)
                            }
                            value={packages[packageIndex].quantity}
                          />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </tbody>
                </Table>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </section>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isError && <Alert color={alertTypes.Danger}>Something went wrong</Alert>}
      {isLoading ? <Spinner /> : <Render />}
    </>
  );
};

const processLabel = photo => { ... };
const processData = data => { ... };
```

Then after each type in quantity input the whole page re-renders, losing focus on the input and moving to the top of the page.

Can someone point me in the right direction on fixing this? I don't want the whole page to re-render and not lose focus on the particular input.

Thanks

Comment: It may have to do with calling `setSelectedPhotos` at the end of `handleUpdateSelection`. I'm not familiar with `produce`, so I'm not sure what it does. Maybe React is stuck in setting that into the `selectedPhotos` state. Have you tried first storing the result of `produce` in a variable and set that instead of the function call?

Comment: @LuudJacobs Yes, I have tried to assign the result of `produce` to a variable and setting that, but is still the same. `produce` is immer (https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction), basically takes an object and produces a new object with your changes

Comment: try removing the slug dependecy in useEffect and replace with `[]` ```useEffect(() => {
        ...
  }, []);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For future reference*

I was able to solve my issue by switching to a class component. Something with hooks and my state data structure wasn't cooperating, I suppose.

I suspect is because `useState` replaces the entire particular state and that was causing the entire page to re-render. As opposed to `this.setState` which merges the state.

Now the only thing re-rendering is the input

Comment: try removing the slug dependecy in useEffect and replace with [] useEffect(() => { ... }, []);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had already tried that but still the same issue. Besides React was complaining about a missing dependency in the useEffect dependency list